# how to return keyboard on textfield while textfield on tableview cell in ios

Tags: iphone, uitableview

how can i return keyboard on textfield while i have put the textfield on cell.contentview , i am using textfieldshouldreturn methodbut its not working So please tell me how can i solve it ? 
this is my code for set textfield on tableview cell

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellidentitifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell * cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellidentitifier];
    if (cell ==nil)
    {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidentitifier];

    }
    else
    {
        [cell prepareForReuse];
    }

    UIImageView *imgview = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 10, 70, 70)];
    imgview.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imgview];

    UITextField *_nameTF = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 10, 160, 22)];
    _nameTF.placeholder =@"Client Name";
    _nameTF.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:_nameTF];
    _nameTF = nil;

    UITextField *_timeTF = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 37, 160, 22)];
    _timeTF.placeholder = @"Time";
    _timeTF.layer.borderWidth= 1.0;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:_timeTF];
    _timeTF = nil;


    UITextField *_PhoneTF = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 64, 160, 22)];
    _PhoneTF.placeholder = @"Phone";
    _PhoneTF.layer.borderWidth= 1.0;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:_PhoneTF];
    _PhoneTF = nil;



    return cell;
}
```

Comment: The 2 ways to get rid of the keyboard are to tell the view to end editing like so: [self.view endEditing:YES]; or tell the text view to resign first responder [textView resignFirsResponder] (this can be called in textfieldshouldreturn if you want to dismiss this way)

Comment: set delegate to self for all textfield and resignfirstresponder in textfieldshouldreturn delegate action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set delegates to textfield in cellForRowAtIndexPath as below, before `return cell` statement.

```
_nameTF.delegate = self;
_timeTF.delegate = self;
_PhoneTF.delegate = self;
```

and

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    return YES;
}
```

and to your `viewcontroller` set delegate as below in .h file

```
@interface myviewVC : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>
```